# Use Vue.js 3 with lodash debounce function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Is there any solution to use lodash debounce on method? I also need 'this' in the function.
Example:

```
data() {
    info: 'Read Me!'
},
methods: {
  readData() {
      console.log(this.info)
  }
}
```

In Vue2 I could use:

```
methods: {
  readData: debounce(function() {
      console.log(this.info)
  }, 500)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data property should be a function that returns an object :

```
data() {
   return{
    info: 'Read Me!'
   }
},
```

and write your method by giving a name to the debounce callback :

```
methods: {
  readData: debounce(function debounceRead() {
      console.log(this.info)
  }, 500)
}
```